# Sublayer no se muestra

Tags: swift, swift3

Teniendo este código:

```
private let topView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 216, green: 216, blue: 216)
    return view
}()

private lazy var typeLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.text = self.searchType == SearchType.why ? "Why" : "What"
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 28)
    return label
}()

private func setupViews() {
        self.view.addSubview(topView)
        self.topView.addSubview(typeLabel)

        self.view.addSubview(tableView)

        self.topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.topView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.topView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        self.topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/8).isActive = true

        self.typeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        self.typeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.typeLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/4).isActive = true

    }



 private func borderLayer(position: CGPoint?, size: CGSize?) -> CALayer {
        let borderLayer = CALayer()

        borderLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        borderLayer.name = "Border"

        borderLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        borderLayer.position = position == nil ? CGPoint.zero : position!
        borderLayer.bounds.size = size == nil ? CGSize.zero : size!

        borderLayer.borderWidth = 5
        borderLayer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        borderLayer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        borderLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 20,height: 20)

        return borderLayer
    }
```

El problema reside en que el `borderLayer` de mi `typeLabel` no se muestra. La posición y el tamaño son correctos. Hice la prueba poniéndole el `borderLayer` a `topView` y se muestra correctamente, ahora el problema es cuando se lo agrega a la vista hija de `topView`. ¿En que me estoy equivocando para que no se muestre el layer?

Código completo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Bifi1jRejMVEZVUU1STVFNbTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ¿Pues agregar el código de ejemplo en formato ZIP? No deja descargarlo ni verlo...

Comment: Intenta ahora, ya di los permisos de descarga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifica las siguientes partes de tu código;

**addViewBorderLayer(view: UIView)**

```
private func addViewBorderLayer(view: UIView) {

    view.layoutIfNeeded() // Añade esto al principio de todo

    [...]

}
```

**borderLayer(position: CGPoint?, size: CGSize?)**

```
private func borderLayer(position: CGPoint?, size: CGSize?) -> CALayer {

    let borderLayer = CALayer()
    borderLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

    [...]

    borderLayer.position = CGPoint(x: size!.width, y: size!.height)

    [...]

}
```

**Actualización 1**

Cambiando esas dos líneas, obtengo el resultado siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sigue sin mostrarse nada, pero para mi el problema no viene de el anchorPoint o la posición porque si el mismo borde se lo agrego a la vista padre(`topView`) si funciona como debe

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta con lo que consigo yo. Te paso el ejemplo que he hecho yo: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ejvpcx65jrpxqnu/Test.zip?dl=0

Comment: Si, ahi ya me anduvo, muchas gracias